# RFC4646 culture codes for javascript

Tags: javascript, list, culture, wps

Is there a comprehensive list of all or most used (e.g. on the websites in www) culture codes regarding to [RFC4646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4646) that is already written in a machine readable format (better: JSON)?

Example:

```
{ codes: [
  { code: 'en-US', name: 'English - United States'},
  { code: 'en-CA', name: 'English - Canada'},
  { code: 'de-DE', name: 'German - Germany'},
  ...
]}
```

I want to know if there is a preferred list of country codes usually used in e.g. GUIs to select localization of the data represented. I have to give the user of my client the possibility to choose a country code that suits best for its needs. I will use the list for form values of an OpenSource client for accessing WPS (Web Processing Service) servers. WPS uses the selected language for localization of its output data. Since WPS is generic as well as the client, there is no context information that allows me to choose a language for the user: The user alone must finally choose a language.

Comment: Surely the contents will depend upon your eventual usage of the data?

Comment: Exactly, what do you need to use these codes for?

Comment: "best practise" for what? Surely you can simply put all codes in a JSON list, but what do you want to do with them?

Comment: @TedBarth: We don't understand what you are asking for. Do you want us to compile a list of the most commonly used culture codes or what?

Comment: I want to know if there is a preferred list of country codes commonly used in e.g. GUIs to select localization of the data represented. I have to give the user of my client the possibility to choose a country code that suits best for its needs.

Comment: "Preferred" by whom? Surely the list of countries depends on the business needs of your client.

Comment: That's the problem: It's not defined. WPS and the client could be used everywhere for everything. The WPS server is unknown and the client is generic. I could give the user a free textfield to enter a code but a list of all codes (with the most used at top) or a small subset for beginners would be better. WPS is a www protocol and so a the ordering could be depended on country codes mostly used on webpages.

Comment: That's not really a question we can answer here. Maybe http://opendata.stackexchange.com is apropos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

you could parse the first and third column

Comment: That's perfect. Didn't know that there were so few codes. Expected around 1000 entries or so.

Comment: I made a JSON file out of it:
https://gist.github.com/tedbarth/3856304ac78e5cb853d3

Comment: And (for the sake of laziness) a Javascript variant:
https://gist.github.com/tedbarth/d7688c24835d39f13291